# Replace one string to another string having forward slash (in both the string) using sed

Tags: sed, replace

I have one file i need to replace below src string to dst string with below values.

```
src="59/291259.wav"
dest="58/291258.wav"

echo "source string= $src    replacement string= $dest"
```

I'm trying below sed command, but getting below errors. could anyone help on thihs.

```
sed -i "s/$src/$dest/g" test.xml
```

Error: 
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'

Comment: This question is now cross-posted on Unix+Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534077/replace-one-string-to-another-string-having-forward-slash-in-both-the-string-u

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If using Bash, then replace the slashes with backslash-prefixed ones:

```
sed -i "s/${src//\//\\/}/${dest//\//\\/}/g" test.xml
```

This is more robust than trying to find an alternate delimiter that "can't occur" within the variables.

You may want to replace other sed-significant characters, such as `&` within `$dest`, and `\` itself in both.

Comment: after using above sed still getting the error.

source string= 59/291259.wav    replacement string= 58/291258.wav
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Sorry about the typo @Sajid - I've fixed it now.

Comment: Thanks, @Toby. It's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

Sed is getting confused by the slashes in your strings. Try using a different delimiter:

```
sed -i "s|$src|$dest|g" test.xml
```

Comment: Can you be sure that `$src` and `$dest` will never contain `|`?

Comment: @TobySpeight: Good point.

Comment: But in my script i have slash as string. like below.

/apps/files/data/56/song.wav --> this i have to replace with /apps/files/datadir/57/song2.wav

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes in my $src and $dest will never contain |. it contains only /.